# Submit form POST to another page but validate before redirect and keep on same page if validation fails

Tags: php, forms, validation

Is there a php way to validate a form that goes submitted to another page before submitting and stay on same page if fields are not valid or if everything valid send post data to another page?

Example would be:
I am on page `somesite.com/orderitems` and there would be form like

```
<form method="post" id="orderform" action="somesite.com/shoppingcart">
   <input type="number" name="numitems" id="numitems" value="1">
   <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
</form>
```

So google chrome for example already knows to validate if you put in input field `required` value and to validate date and number fields. I have also a jquery datepicker so user can select date easily, and also jquery validator to validate fields before submit, but all this can be overridden and/or fail at some point.

So end point would be validation in php when form is submitted.

But what i am stumbled upon is that i can't use GET request in getting data on `somesite.com/shoppingcart` so i must send POST to that page, but if some of the field fail to validate, like wrong date or wrong date format, than i shouldn't even go (redirect or post) to `somesite.com/shoppingcart`, instead i should stay on the page `somesite.com/orderitems` and display the errors.

So is there a solution to something like this, what suggestions would you recommend. Can i post form to the same page and validate fields if, all is good than redirect to another page and pass POST data, or stay on same page and display error?

Comment: What you're asking for is called AJAX

Comment: AJAX, or make a validation in shoppingcart - ifeverything is okay, continue in order process. If not, save `$_POST` items into session, prepare an error message and redirect back to `orderitems`. Values in inputs will be prefilled from session.

Comment: Huh that sound's overly complicated. I use WordPress site for this and although i've used ajax before on it, i still don't get it how would ajax redirect after post is success. For that i would have to read further more, is there a way without ajax since some mobile browsers can make trouble with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will show you how this can be done via JavaScript/Ajax and PHP. I think it won't be difficult to learn doing it from this tutorial, but if some questions arise I am ready to help you.

#### JavaScript/Ajax request

First of all, we need to add `"Submit"` button to form and set `"sendData()"` function as its **"onclick"** listener. Which means each time you click on `"Submit"` button, `"sendData()"` function will execute. Also, we need to add 'class' attribute to 'number' and 'date' input elements, to get their values in more cleaner way.

```
<form method="post" id="orderform" action="somesite.com/shoppingcart">
   <input type="number" class='myForm' name="numitems" id="numitems" value="1">
   <input type="date" class='myForm' name="date" id="date">
   <input type="Submit" value="Send" onclick = sendData(); return false;"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function sendData()
{
    var formElements = document.querySelectorAll(".myForm"); // We use 'class' attribute to get form elements (number and date).
    var formData = new FormData(); // we create FormData object with which we can send data to "PHP" script (server side).
    for(var i = 0; i < formElements.length; i++)
    {
        formData.append(formElements[i].name, formElements[i].value);
    }
    //AJAX Starts Here
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Create "ajax" object
        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() //This is to wait for response from your PHP script
        {
            if(xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200) //And when status is OK use result
            {
                var responseText = xmlHttp.responseText; //here you save your response from server side.
                if(responseText["Status"] === "OK") //if you send from server side that "Status" is OK, then you can go to that page
                {
                    window.location.href = "somesite.com/shoppingcart";
                }
                else //otherwise you refresh page
                {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("POST", "somesite.com/shoppingcart"); //set page value, where you want to send form values
        xmlHttp.send(formData); //send actual data
}

</script>
```

#### PHP validation (to avoid manipulation/override on client-side)

When you validate values in server-side, set `$_SESSION["Status"] = "OK"`.
After that if someone tries to **"hack"** your page and **"change"** your JavaScript functions to navigate to somesite.com/shoppingcart page, you will check:

somesite.com/shoppingcart

```
<?php
    if($_SESSION["Status"] === "OK"])
    {
       //give permission
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Looks like ill be going with this method, not exactly like example but this help me in direction how i should go with it since there is not php only solution.

Answer (score 0):

i am also facing this problem. and i solve it by doing this

**UPDATE**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $('#orderform').validate({
        rules: {
            numitems: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            },
            date: {
                required: true,
                date: true
            }
        }
    });

    $('#orderform input').on('keyup blur', function () {
        if ($('#orderform').valid()) {
           $("#button1").removeClass("submit");
           //TRIGGER FORM 
           //$('#orderform').submit();
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.submit{
  user-select: none;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form method="post" id="orderform" action="somesite.com/shoppingcart">
   <input type="number" name="numitems" id="numitems"><br/>
   <input type="date" name="date" id="date"><br/>
   <span class="submit" id="button1">SUBMIT</span>
</form>
```

i Hope it helps.!

Comment: I am also using jQuery validate, but problem is, user can still post form and override validation just by removing jquery validate code with chrome developer tool, so still need php validation

Comment: so for that use span or other and create your own class to disable span tag and than if all field is valid remove that class.

Comment: See i post Update